# Testing actions invoked by event in jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Basicaly I have to test if action that should be invoked by event is in fact invoked (not if event is fired). For example I want to test if on `foo` event some method `obj.bar` is invoked:

```
emitter.on('foo', function() { obj.bar(); });
```

`obj` of course has spy on `bar` method. I've tried calling done callback when `obj.bar` is invoked via `.and.callFake`, but it's not working, it says that `obj.bar` wasn't invoked at all. Actual code looks like this (I'm using ES6)

```
it('rejects invalid packet', done => {
    let packet = client.fake('system/login', { // fakes incoming packet by calling proper event.
        email: 'nope@test.dev'
    });

    client.reply.and.callFake(() => done());

    expect(client.reply).toHaveBeenCalledWith(packet, 'system/login', {
        code: ResponseCode.INVALID_PACKET
    });
});
```

How to properly assure that spy was invoked on event (or any other async method)?